# "linker sets" on hybrid clang Windows driver

Tags: c, windows, linker, clang, driver

OK so very special situation here, so it is somewhat gross and the answer is probably no.
Compiling a project with clang (as it is Unix source) into .libs, but linking with MSVC++ for "/driver" to make the kernel component.

Looking for a way to handle Linux `MODULE_PARAM()` where they can define `static int tunable;` and have it be changeable for the kernel. Probably to be made into Registry entries, that seems to be how Windows would do the equivalent of sysctl, or kstat, or /proc

This could easily be handled by a "linker set", using `SET_ENTRY(tunable)` and then `SET_FOREACH()` to loop through them all.

Having some issues to get them to work, I suspect because of linking with MSVC++, so I might not be able to make it work. But maybe you guys can think of a way around.

Using:

```
#define __MAKE_SET_CONST const

#define __STRING(x) #x      /* stringify without expanding x */
#define __XSTRING(x)    __STRING(x) /* expand x, then stringify */

#define __GLOBL(sym)    __asm__(".globl " __XSTRING(sym))
#define __WEAK(sym) __asm__(".weak " __XSTRING(sym))

#define __CONCAT1(x, y) x ## y
#define __CONCAT(x, y)  __CONCAT1(x, y)

#define __used      __attribute__((__used__))
#define __section(x)    __attribute__((__section__(x)))
#define __nosanitizeaddress __attribute__((no_sanitize("address")))
#define __weak_symbol   __attribute__((__weak__))

#define __MAKE_SET_QV(set, sym, qv)         \
    __WEAK(__CONCAT(__start_set_,set));     \
    __WEAK(__CONCAT(__stop_set_,set));      \
    static void const * qv              \
    __set_##set##_sym_##sym __section("set_" #set)  \
    __nosanitizeaddress             \
    __used = &(sym)
#define __MAKE_SET(set, sym)    __MAKE_SET_QV(set, sym, __MAKE_SET_CONST)

#define TEXT_SET(set, sym)  __MAKE_SET(set, sym)
#define DATA_SET(set, sym)  __MAKE_SET(set, sym)
#define DATA_WSET(set, sym) __MAKE_SET_QV(set, sym, )
#define BSS_SET(set, sym)   __MAKE_SET(set, sym)
#define ABS_SET(set, sym)   __MAKE_SET(set, sym)
#define SET_ENTRY(set, sym) __MAKE_SET(set, sym)

static int settest1 = 58;
static int settest2 = 156;

SET_ENTRY(testset, settest1);
SET_ENTRY(testset, settest2);

#define SET_BEGIN(set)                          \
    (&__CONCAT(__start_set_,set))
#define SET_LIMIT(set)                          \
    (&__CONCAT(__stop_set_,set))

#define SET_DECLARE(set, ptype)                 \
    extern ptype __weak_symbol *__CONCAT(__start_set_,set); \
    extern ptype __weak_symbol *__CONCAT(__stop_set_,set)

#define SET_FOREACH(pvar, set)                      \
    for (pvar = SET_BEGIN(set); pvar < SET_LIMIT(set); pvar++)

void
linkersettest(void)
{
    SET_DECLARE(testset, int);

    int **ptr;
    SET_FOREACH(ptr, testset) {
    int x = **ptr;
    KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL,
        "linkerset test: %d\n", x));
    }
}
```

Compiling (clang) seems ok, but alas, linking (MSVC++) says:

`error LNK2016: absolute symbol '__start_set_testset' used as target of REL32 relocation in section 0x1`

Comment: Oh ah interesting. I assumed "clang" would do "what's right" here, but of course that is "what's right for Windows", so it does put the __start_set_testset into REL32 section.  I can get around that by adding a `__declspec(dllexport) int * __CONCAT(__start_set_,set);` before the WEAK. Now it links, but dies when trying out SET_FOREACH. The ptr points to `0xfffff807325f5898` but there is nothing but 00s there.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add new information. Down here in the comments it tends to be unread.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve here. It seems like you're trying to compile Linux kernel module code as is and (with the help of some macro magic) have it work in Windows. If that is the case, why? Just #ifdef separate Linux/Windows specifics.

Comment: The port of ZFS from Linux does work, so I don't think we need to go into that. I want to minimize changes to upstream to fit this port though. I am simply exploring options to handle the specific case of MODULE_PARAM, since those tunables are generally statically defined in each source file. This problem on macOS, which can not do linker-sets, I handled with "attribute(constructor)". Of course I can just have a manual list of wrapped static tunables - but thought I'd explore more fun coding ideas. If linker-sets don't work, I'll look at something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making changes like:

```
    static void const * qv              \
    __set_##set##_sym_##sym __section("set_" #set)  \
```

The `static` here on Windows will drop it from .obj file. Removing `static` and going with:

```
    __declspec(dllexport) void const * qv               \
    __set_##set##_sym_##sym __section("set_" #set)  \
```

gets us all the expected defines in the .obj file, including `__set_testset_sym_settest1` and `__start_set_testset`.

But it doesn't work, in that it does not appear to make a linker section `set_testset` at all, and the mentioned symbols are "randomly" in side, not the expected `start, settest1, settest2, stop`.

While looking around examples of `#pragma section(".CRT$XCU",read,write)` to add constructors to CRT's initterm, I came across this snippet:

```
typedef void(__cdecl* PF)(void);

#pragma section(".mine$a", read)
__declspec(allocate(".mine$a")) const PF InitSegStart = (PF)1;
#pragma section(".mine$z",read)
__declspec(allocate(".mine$z")) const PF InitSegEnd = (PF)1;

__declspec(allocate(".mine$m")) const PF __set_settest1 = (PF)&settest1;
__declspec(allocate(".mine$m")) const PF __set_settest2 = (PF)&settest2;

void
linkersettest(void)
{
    const PF* x = &InitSegStart;
    DbgBreakPoint();
    for (++x; x < &InitSegEnd; ++x)
    KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL,
        "linkerset test: %p %p %d\n", x, *x, *(int *)*x ));
```

Which appears to be the way Windows would do "linker-sets", and it works.

Possibly the clang way will work, if I adjust the section name from `set_testset` to a Windows name like `.mine$` and ensure start/stop is "a" and "z" respectively.

I assume the "m" is just any character, as long as it is between "a" and "z", to get the order.

Should the setting of `.mime$m` be preceded by a `#pragma` line? I've not looked at what `#pragma section read` line does, yet (but works without it).

Comment: OK I have it working, staying with Unix API:  https://github.com/openzfsonwindows/openzfs/pull/78/commits/e81c43a19ebd935b4101bd37b0475a23c55db461